# How to edit an existing VSTO for an Outlook Add-in

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I am a complete beginner to using VSTO and I have been asked to modify an existing Add-in within Outlook.  The Add-in is just a button that is used to forward an email to a specific email address, but before it creates the email it presents a really basic input box with a couple of questions.

I have installed Visual Studio and can view the vsto file.  I can see it has the following line which I presume is what I need to look at.

```
<dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\Email Forward_1_0_0_9\Email Forward.dll.manifest" size="12358">
```

And I can see within the manifest file above that it has:

```
 <vstav3:entryPoint class="companyXYZ_buttons.ThisAddIn">
```

From the little I understand, the actual code is within ThisAddIn and I believe it was written in VB.  If I can get to the VB, I am reasonably proficient in VBA so can probably sort out the change I need to do.

Please note that when I look at the Add-in within Outlook it shows as type **COM**.

Because this is so new to me, I've tried using Google but I don't even know what terminology to search for.  I have found various Microsoft articles but nothing about modifying existing Outlook Add-ins.  Just looking for someone to point me in the right direction please.

Comment: That looks like the click-once deployment folder. You'll need to get the whole project. Do a search for *.SLN for the solution file for the project.

Comment: Thanks, I've just finished work for the day, will check on Monday.

Comment: Sorry for the late update.  We couldn't find the .SLN file so someone must have created it on another PC to where the deployment folder was :(

Comment: I'd check who created the deployed files and see if you can chase it up that way.

Comment: Thank you. The person has long gone from the company unfortunately. Looks like I'm going to have to learn from the beginning.

Comment: I have a bunch of example projects for vsto. Most of the good ones are for Excel, but you would be able to import classes, etc. Hope this helps. https://github.com/Excel-projects

Comment: Thank you.  Really struggling to find Outlook specific stuff.  I know some parts are transferable, but even the "getting started" info out there seems to favor Excel.  I was just playing around with Visual Studio - created a VB Outlook VSTO Add-in project, added a Ribbon (Visual designer) with a button that doesn't do anything yet.  I built it and can see the Add-in gets loaded when I open Outlook, but don't know how to get the ribbon I created to show.